# awk and grep with filter?

Tags: awk, grep, find

This is my log file i want to filter,

```
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoprogress;status=first;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=IN;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoprogress;status=mid;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=US;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoprogress;status=third;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=US;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoprogress;status=complete;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=IN;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoothers;status=pause;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=IN;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoothers;status=mute;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1547;cid=IN;cpid=1547
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoothers;status=unmute;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df655;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1545;cid=IN;cpid=1545
xxxyyy.com/plugins/status.gif?type=videoothers;status=error;sid=6941c712-ca83-4aa1-a69a-931ca66df656;vid=606829;vrid=61478182;pid=1546;cid=IN;cpid=1546
```

I need output like this

```
pid  cid cpid Count  
1545 IN  1545   4  
1545 US  1545   2  
1546 IN  1546   1    
1547 IN  1547   1
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: on what basis u need the count to be incremented?... based on pid/cid/cpid/all??? downvote is not from me by the way.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty:

```
kent$  awk -F';' '{a[$(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1) OFS $NF]++}
                   END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
pid=1547 cid=IN cpid=1547 1
pid=1545 cid=US cpid=1545 2
pid=1546 cid=IN cpid=1546 1
pid=1545 cid=IN cpid=1545 4
```

now you can adjust the output to fit your required format.

Answer (score 0):

A very little different than kent one:

```
awk -F';' '{ split($6,pid,"="); split($7,cid,"="); split($8,cpid,"="); n[pid[2] OFS cid[2] OFS cpid[2]]++; } END { print "pid","cid","cpid","count"; for (p in n) { print p,n[p] } }' input.txt
```

gives:

```
pid cid cpid count
1545 IN 1545 4
1545 US 1545 2
1546 IN 1546 1
1547 IN 1547 1
```

Just the code with comments

```
{ 
  split($6,pid,"="); split($7,cid,"="); split($8,cpid,"="); # Get the numbers from each pair in an array
  n[pid[2] OFS cid[2] OFS cpid[2]]++; # count the tuples from the numbers (create an array with the tuples as key and increment it)
} 
END { 
  print "pid","cid","cpid","count"; # print the header
  for (p in n) { print p,n[p] } # print the key (tuples) and the count of it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way, similar to the others

```
awk -F';' '{for(i=0;i<3;i++){split($(NF-i),a,"=");x=a[2]" "x;NR==1&&y=a[1]" "y}
            b[x]++;x=z}END{print y "count";for(i in b)print i b[i]}' file
```

Extracts the value and name of the pair, then increments an array using the values as a key.
Print out the extracted headers and the new `count` header.
Loops the array printing out the key(values) and the number of occurences

#### Output

```
pid cid cpid count
1547 IN 1547 1
1545 IN 1545 4
1546 IN 1546 1
1545 US 1545 2
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't took the time to factorize the header/split calls and though it would get complicated to understand for a newcomer. For my knowledge, is the a reason to use space over OFS is that the affectation could not use it as is and would have require a call to sprintf ? (unsure of this last point)

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks :) No you could use OFS if you want, just a personal preference. As long as the separator doesn't appear in the text then you can use whatever you want :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got use to OFS so when a space comes too short, adding a -vOFS="\t" at command line comes in handy for output in columns :)